# Images got uploaded on AWS S3 bucket but it's not showing on Django heroku app

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I pushed my django app on heroku and i am able to upload media files from my website admin pannel to AWS s3 bucket. But those media files doesn't render on the website.
***here is my settings files***

```
import os
import datetime
AWS_USERNAME = 'rahul'
AWS_GROUP_NAME = 'new_brdy_eng_group'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("xxxxxxxxxx") 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('xxxxxxxxxxx') 

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'BE.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'BE.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'brdy-engineers'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'ap-south-1'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

I changed ***MEDIA_URL*** like these also

```
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = 'https://brdy-engineers.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://brdy-engineers.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/media/Homefiles/reviews/'
```

**But None of these worked**

**utils.py file**

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='media')
```

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::brdy-engineers/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket CORS**

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

**Bucket Block all public access is off**

*I added current user to group policy that is*

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::brdy-engineers"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object*",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::brdy-engineers/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the problem here, why i'm not able to access images on heroku app?

Comment: Can you share the client request from the browser?

Comment: http://sell-this-site.herokuapp.com/

Comment: from what I see on this page for example:
https://sell-this-site.herokuapp.com/products/detail/rahul-verma/

the images get 403, https://brdy-engineers.s3.amazonaws.com/media/Images/pexels-pixabay-67857.jpg. Try making them public if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings here and then optimize it as you need:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error when setting up ours.

If I remember correctly, `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True` solved it for us. As we wanted some files, for certain models, to be accessible only to members of some group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't need to change default static or media url. Here I use an logic if `AWS = True` because If anytime you want to stop using aws s3 service then you will just change the value == Flase and all static and media content will be serve from your hsoting server.

```
AWS = True

    if AWS:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
            AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
            AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = config('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN')
            AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = config('AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS')
            AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = config('AWS_DEFAULT_ACL')
            AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = config('AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE')
            AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = config('AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH')
            DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = config('DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE')
            AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
            STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
            STATICFILES_STORAGE = config('STATICFILES_STORAGE')
     else:
          STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'



MEDIA_ROOT = '' #add path of your hosting folder where static  file located 

STATIC_ROOT = '' #add path of your hosting folder where media  file located
```

in your root **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)     
]

urlpatterns +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also you need to be add follwing permission on your aws s3 bucket:

uncheck all Block public access (bucket settings)

[image]

Block public access should be turned off
[image]

**add Bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "****", put your own 
    "Id": "******", put your own 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::: your bucket name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**you need to be enabled ACLs**
[image]

Then add list and write permission for everyone from **Access control list (ACL)**
[image]

then add  **Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)**

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```